# Python: Best way to deal with functions with long list of arguments?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, arguments

I've found various detailed explanations on how to pass long lists of arguments into a function, but I still kinda doubt if that's proper way to do it.

In other words, I *suspect* that I'm doing it wrong, but I can't see how to do it *right*.

The problem: I have (not very long) recurrent function, which uses quite a number of variables and needs to modify some content in at least some of them.

What I end up with is sth like this:

```
def myFunction(alpha, beta, gamma, zeta, alphaList, betaList, gammaList, zetaList):
    <some operations>
    myFunction(alpha, beta, modGamma, zeta, modAlphaList, betaList, gammaList, modZetaList)
```

...and I want to see the changes I did on original variables (in C I would just pass a reference, but I hear that in Python it's always a copy?).

Sorry if noob, I don't know how to phrase this question so I can find relevant answers.

Comment: Could you give a concrete example?

Comment: In python it's _never_ a copy

Comment: This answer will help you to understand how parameters behave regarding reference --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/15931

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could wrap up all your parameters in a class, like this:

```
class FooParameters:
    alpha = 1.0
    beta = 1.0
    gamma = 1.0
    zeta = 1.0
    alphaList = []
    betaList = []
    gammaList = []
    zetaList = []
```

and then your function takes a single parameter instance:

```
def myFunction(params):
    omega = params.alpha * params.beta + exp(params.gamma)
    # more magic...
```

calling like:

```
testParams = FooParameters()
testParams.gamma = 2.3
myFunction(testParams)
print params.zetaList
```

Because the params instance is passed by *reference*, changes in the function are preserved.

Answer (score 8):

This is commonly used in `matplotlib`, for example, where a large number of arguments can be conveniently passed using `*` or `**`:

```
def function(*args, **kwargs):
    do something
```

Calling the function:

```
function(1,2,3,4,5, a=1, b=2, b=3)
```

where the listed arguments `1,2,3,4,5` will go to `args` whereas the named arguments `a=1, b=2, c=3` will go to `kwargs`, as a dictionary. The listed and named arguments arrive at your function as:

```
args = [1,2,3,4,5]
kwargs = {a:1, b:2, c:3}
```

Making it convenient to use them inside the function.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know where you got the idea that Python copies values when passing into a function. That is *not at all* true.

On the contrary: each parameter in a function is an additional name referring to the original object. If you change *the value* of that object in some way - for example, if it's a list and you change one of its members - then the original will also see that change. But if you *rebind* the name to something else - say by doing `alpha = my_completely_new_value` - then the original remains unchanged.

Comment: While it is technically correct to say *"each parameter in a function is an additional name referring to the original object"*, the behaviour for immutable types is not the one someone would expect to be for a variable passed "by reference" (as in C). If an `int`  parameter is changed within the function (say, by doing  `alpha += 1`), the original variable will not be affected.

Comment: Technically, python (just like any other major programming language, by default at least) uses "pass by value" semantics. that's where he got the idea from. And yes, it is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You may be tempted to something akin to this:

```
def myFunction(*args):
    var_names = ['alpha','beta','gamma','zeta']
    locals().update(zip(var_names,args))
    myFunction(alpha,beta,gamma,zeta)
```

However, this 'often' won't work. I suggest introducing another namespace:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def myFunction(*args):
    var_names = ['alpha','beta','gamma','zeta']
    vars = OrderedDict(zip(var_names,args))

    #get them all via vars[var_name]

    myFunction(*vars.values()) #since we used an orderedDict we can simply do *.values()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can capture the non-modfied values in a closure:

```
def myFunction(alpha, beta, gamma, zeta, alphaList, betaList, gammaList, zetaList):
    def myInner(g=gamma, al, zl):
        <some operations>
        myInner(modGamma, modAlphaList, modZetaList)
    myInner(al=alphaList, zl=zetaList)
```

(BTW, this is about the only way to write a truly recursive function in Python.)

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in a dictionary and return a new dictionary. Or put your method in a class and have alpha, beta etc. be attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You should put `myFunction` in a class. Set up the class with the appropriate attributes and call the appropriate functions. The state is then well contained in the class.